# How to remove 4th letter in string using PHP?

Tags: php, substr

How to remove 4th letter in string using PHP ?

I use this code.

```
<?php
$str = "1234567890";
$str2 = mb_substr($str, 4);
echo $str2;
?>
```

But it's will echo `567890`

I want to echo `123567890` remove `4` from string.

How can i do ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`substr_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) for this. Here we are replacing `4` which is at `3rd` index.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/895976)

```
<?php
$str = "1234567890";
echo substr_replace($str, "", 3,1);
```

Comment: I've a question... Why 'ltrim($str, 4);' is not working...? Thanks

Comment: @GyandeepSharma `ltrim` is for trimming a string from left, not for removing/replacing a substring from string.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the 3rd index to null

```
<?php
$str = "1234567890";
$str[3] = null;
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

try with below sulution:

```
$str = '1234567890';
$str_arr = str_split($str);
unset($str_arr[3]);
echo implode('', $str_arr);
```

output:

```
123567890
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of performing any operations on string variables in php

```
// can be used for printing purpose
$str = "1234567890";
echo substr($str,0,3).substr($str,4);

// actual replacement of string
$str = "1234567890";
echo substr_replace($str, "", 3,1);
```